# Grails - Querying a domain instance's properties' properties

Tags: grails

So far all the examples of queries I am coming across are geared towards a domain class such as:

`Account.where, Account.withCriteria, Account.findxxxx` but what if I want to query an **instance's properties' properties**? For example what if I have `c` a company instance that has a department `d` and I want to get a `list of all the departments` of this company instance that have 12 employees (a property of department) or less? What would be the code for such a query?

Something like:

```
c.findAllD's(such that d.numberOfEmployees <= 12)
```

Also, can anyone point me to literature on such instance based queries? I haven't been able to come across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to make the association bidirectional, i.e.

```
class Company {
  static hasMany = [departments:Department]
}

class Department {
  Company company
  int numberOfEmployees

  static belongsTo = [company:Company]
}
```

Then you can simply start your queries from the `Department` end, such as

```
def c = Company.get(...) // or however you obtain your Company instance
def departments = Department.findAllByCompanyAndNumberOfEmployeesLessThanEquals(c, 12)
```

Comment: Is the line `Company company` necessary in the `Department` class even though we have declared below it that a department belongs to a company? Wouldn't that declaration in itself hold the reference to the owner company of a department? I think it is for bidirectionality correct?

Comment: @AnonymousHuman that line may indeed be redundant, but it doesn't do any harm to include it.

Comment: I see, thanks. You used '12' as the argument to Company.get(12), why?

Comment: @AnonymousHuman there was no significance to that choice, I've edited to make things clearer.

Comment: I thought as much but just wanted to make sure. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you want to use the [Named Queries](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)